# Will Cobalt have plan to support other web app?

Tags: cobalt

1. Will Cobalt support other web apps in the future?
   e.g Pandora/Amazon/FB...etc.
2. Does Cobalt have plugin mechanism?
   e.g NPAPI/QT bridge

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, Cobalt can be used to build any web apps, assuming that web app developers are willing to work within Cobalt HTML5 subset.
2. No, we don't plan to support plugins at the moment due to the fact that a significant number of target platforms do not allow execution of dynamically loaded/generated code.